# Visual Studio Code powershell terminal display is broken

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

I am using VisualStudioCode with powershell, and the line breaks as shown below.

[image]

Do you have any idea why?

VisualStudioCode Version:

[image]

My settings file:

```
{
    "editor.fontFamily": "D2Coding",
    "editor.fontSize": 14,
    "editor.wordWrap": "on",
    "editor.mouseWheelZoom": true,
    "window.reopenFolders": "none",
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Visual Studio Dark",
    "workbench.welcome.enabled": false,
    "window.zoomLevel": 0,
    "editor.cursorStyle": "line-thin",
    "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Windows\\SysWOW64\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe"
}
```

Comment: Have you tried moving the settings file to a different location and restarting Visual Studio Code? If the console works with no settings file you will know that it's a problem with the settings. If it happens with no setting files you should follow the instructions on the Extension to log an issue on the GitHub page.

Comment: I deleted the configuration file and confirmed that the settings were initialized, but the symptoms still exist.

Answer (score 1):

You should not be using the "SysWOW64" path for your powershell.exe console.

Update your terminal setting to this:

```
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Windows\\sysnative\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe"
```

If you are running Windows 10 you can remove it all together as VS Code will default to PowerShell as the terminal for Windows.

Comment: I changed it to 'sysnative' but I still have symptoms.

Comment: And when you open a PowerShell process outside of Code you don't have the issue? Do you e same results in the integrated terminal?

Comment: Yes, opening powershell from the outside is no problem, and it only becomes a problem when opened in a shell with visual studio code integration.

Comment: Submit an issue to the vs-code-powershell extension repo. Expect could be a bug bit will be something specific to your device. I don't have that issue in mine.

Comment: thank you. I'll do that, if the results are good I'll share it ^^

Comment: According to the vscode powershell developer, this issue is a problem with the win10 creator version.
Please refer to ~
https://github.com/PowerShell/vscode-powershell/issues/833